# how do i extract both the week and year off a date, and have it as week1, 2022 or week40, 2021

Tags: google-bigquery, bigdata

I initially extracted the weeks from a date as 1, 2, 3 using the extract clause but now, I want to have the year along with it as week1, 2022 or week 40, 2021

Answer (score 0):

Use below

```
select format_date('week%W, %Y', current_date())
```

with output as

[image]